# Wordpress onepage theme with AJAX blog

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery

I have implemented a one page theme for all wordpress pages, this is working seamlessly. The only bit im struggling with is how I would incorporate the blog into this theme. It would be great to turn the categories and posts into a one page ajax blog.

Therefore my questions are:

Whats the best way to implement this, does anyone have any comments/suggestions, Advantages/Disadvantages.

What effect would this have on SEO, how would each post be crawled? Would I need to use mod_rewrite/ hash tags?

Thanks in advance for ANY help.

Answer (score 0):

Blogs can coexist with one page sites absolutely fine.

There is no downsides of this really apart from not everything is on one page! but blogs grow and they are not ideally for one page sites.

You could use a AJAX to fetch the pages like in an ISOTOPE, look up Jquery Isotope and you're be presented with lots of nice Gizmos. Personally I like this style but like the page to go somewhere, Ajax is good but don't over do it! or if you do ensure that these pages are indexable.

As far as mod-rewrite, just install Yoast SEO from the Wordpress Plugin thingie, You shouldn't need anything hardcore since on your menu as long as it has the hash tags it should go back to the first page and then scroll down, or go straight to that position.

Sadly one page sites are hard to rank seriously on Google unless you have a zillion links or a handful of extremely quality ones! I'd recommend going with a One Page + Multiple Page Blog. If you wanted to keep things even more simplerly you could always install the Blog on another wordpress install within /blog/ keeping both systems apart. Personally I'd opt to use that because then you could only use the plugins on the first page that you need too and not have to worry about dequeuing them for extra speed.

Fact is there's no real right way of doing this, just whatever way works best for you.

Depending how your template is made you may need to install a [Wordpress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in it.

Good Luck ;)